# Exponential fit overflow compilation error

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I don't know what am doing wrong.

`amount={20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200}`

`capa={12,32,50,65,87,110,145,185,320,380,445,510,580,650,710,790,860}`

`data=Transpose[{amount,capa}]`

`nlm=NonlinearModelFit[data,A*(1-Exp[-b*x]),{A,B},x]`

Using this I get overflow compilation error and nothing happens.

When I use the exact same fit in Origin or Matplotlib I get correct fit with `A=-135`and `B=-0.01017`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you could read on the Documentation page for the `"General::ovfl"` message you got, the problem here possible in bad starting values chosen by `NonlinearModelFit`. Let us try to specify better starting values:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*(1 - Exp[-b*x]), {{a, -1}, {b, 0}}, x];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]

(*=> {a -> -134.847, b -> -0.0101706} *)
```

Right answer and no error messages.